# команда copy ведет себя по-другому, если ее запускать повторно

Tags: svn

Если в svn репозитории file:///C:/SVNMyArc выполнить что-то вроде
svn copy file:///C:/SVNMyArc/A file:///C:/SVNMyArc/B -m "ATOB",
то svn скопирует содержимое директории A в B.
Если выполнить эту команду повторно, то svn скопирует в B директорию A вместе с содержимым А. Таким образом, в В будет:

- содержимое А в директории file:///C:/SVNMyArc/B
- содержимое А в директории file:///C:/SVNMyArc/B/A

Если выполнить эту команду в третий раз, то svn выдаст ошибку, что директория A уже есть.
Можно ли как-то написать параметры команду copy, так чтобы она при повторном запуске понимала, что надо копировать содержимое A, а не саму директорию A с содержимым.

Comment: Это стандартное поведение `cp`. Создайте B заранее и выполняйте копирование по glob-маске: `...Arc/A/*`

Comment: Уточните, пожулуйста, что значит по glob-маске. Если написать svn copy file:///C:/SVNMyArc/A/* file:///C:/SVNMyArc/B -m "ATOB
.",  то получим ошибку
svn: E160013: File not found: revision 4, path '/A/*'